# Simple trick in a integral

Tags: calculus

I am studying a proof of a theorem  and in the proof i have the following equality

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \frac{\left|\sin(2nt)\right|}{t}  \ \mathrm dt= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(t)}{ t + (k-1) \pi}  \ \mathrm dt$$

I am not seeing the trick to obtain this equality. someone can give me a hint?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $u = 2nt$. You get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\lvert\sin (2nt)\rvert}{t}\, dt = \int_0^{n\pi} \frac{\lvert \sin u\rvert}{u}\, du.$$

Now write the latter as a sum,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi} \frac{\lvert \sin u\rvert}{u}\, du$$

and translate each of the integrals to the interval $[0,\pi]$ to obtain

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^\pi \frac{\lvert \sin (t+(k-1)\pi)\rvert}{t+(k-1)\pi}\,dt.$$

Since the sine is nonnegative on $[0,\pi]$, and $\sin (t+m\pi) = (-1)^m\sin t$, the result follows.